# Last header and column in table should be scrollable

Tags: html, css, html-table, scrollable

I am trying to make the last body and header of a normal table scrollable. The table contains 6 columns. The first 5 should be fixed on their position so that the last column should be scrollable, but I have no idea how to build this...

This is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<table id="box-table-a">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">aaa</th>
            <th scope="col">bbb</th>
            <th scope="col">ccc</th>
            <th scope="col">ddd</th>
            <th scope="col">eee</th>
            <th scope="col">fff(very long column very long column very long column very long column very long column very long column very long column very long column very long column very long column very long column very long column very long column very long column very long column very long column very long column very long column very long column )</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>aaa</td>
                <td>bbb</td>
                <td>ccc</td>
                <td>ddd</td>
                <td>eee</td>
                <td>long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text </td>
          </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
        /* ------------------
 styling for the tables 
   ------------------   */


body
{
    line-height: 1.6em;
}


#box-table-a
{
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: left;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
#box-table-a th
{
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    background: #b9c9fe;
    border-top: 0px solid #aabcfe;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #039;


}

#box-table-a th:last-child {
    overflow: scroll;
}

#box-table-a td:last-child {

    overflow: scroll;
}
#box-table-a td
{
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0.0px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    background: #e8edff; 
    border-bottom: 0px solid #fff;
    color: #669;
    border-top: 0px solid transparent;
}
#box-table-a tr:hover td
{
    background: #d0dafd;
    color: #339;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please include your relevant HTML and CSS code here.

Comment: hi,welcome to  SO....show some HTML and CSS that you have done so far...that would help us understand better! :)

Comment: this is what i have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/pTZe4/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr>
            <td>Col 1</td>
            <td>Col 2</td>
            <td>Col 3</td>
            <td>Col 4</td>
            <td>Col 5</td>
            <td width="100px"><div style="overflow-x:auto;width:100px;white-space: nowrap;">col6 col6 col6 col6 ol6 col6</div>  </td>
        </tr>
```

This one works!

Comment: almost that what im trying to make. But the scrollbar should only be under the last column and should scroll all elements in the column. Like if you freeze tables in excel.

Comment: Try setting the width and using overflow-x ?

Comment: Try my latest html. No css needed just the inline styles as above.

Comment: Use this line for the last col;

<td width="100px" style="overflow-x:auto;width:100px;white-space: nowrap;">col6 col6 col6 col6 ol6 col6</td>